# Data binding from a complex ICollectionView in a WPF ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I have the following xaml:

```
<UserControl ... xmlns:dd="clr-namespace:AttachedBehaviours.DragDrop;assembly=AttachedBehaviours" ... >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <dd:BindingProxy x:Key="library_proxy"
                         Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, ElementName=library}" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ListView x:Name="library" ItemsSource="{Binding View}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="dd:DragDropMulti.DragDropPreviewControl">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <dd:DragDropPreviewBase>
                            <dd:DragDropPreviewBase.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="dd:DragDropPreviewBase">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="tblk__preview"
                                               Text="{Binding Binding, Source={StaticResource library_proxy}}" />
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Binding, Source={StaticResource library_proxy}}"
                                                     Value="1">
                                            <DataTrigger.Setters>
                                                <Setter TargetName="tblk__preview"
                                                        Property="Text"
                                                        Value="{Binding Name}" />
                                            </DataTrigger.Setters>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </dd:DragDropPreviewBase.Template>
                        </dd:DragDropPreviewBase>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

The problem I'm having is that if I generate my `ICollectionView` (the "View" in `ItemsSource="{Binding View}"`) with a basic `CollectionViewSource`, everything works as expected. E.g.:

```
View = new CollectionViewSource { Source = Models }.View;
```

However, if I use something more complex, the `Setter` binding of the `DataTrigger` doesn't work. E.g.:

```
View =
    new CollectionViewSource
    {
        Source =
            Models
                .Join(
                    Lookups
                    , model => model.ID
                    , lookup => lookup.Key
                    , (model, lookup) =>
                        new ComplexModel
                        {
                            ID = model.ID,
                            Name = model.Name,
                            Value = lookup.Value
                        }
                )
    }
    .View;
```

I get the error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Name' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindowViewModel' (HashCode=17911681)'.
```

`MainWindowViewModel` is the overall `DataContext` (outside of the `UserControl`), so it's as though the `DataContext` has not been set.

Why would this be the case?

Comment: Try add `.Cast<ComplexModel>().ToArray()` after `Join()`

Comment: @Mikolaytis Thanks, but no luck with that I'm afraid.